# First time ever playing soon, advice?

Tags: new-players

I've always been interested in these sorts of things, rpg, gaming etc, but been too shy to join. Now I've finally joined a dnd 4th ed group and I'm going soon.

I'm positive it's my thing, but I'm not totally ready to buy stuff yet. So, what can I do to prepare? I already have a group of characters that I know intimately, could I bring them and adapt/specify as needed or am I expected to build one from scratch every time?

What should I expect? A friend took me to a gaming hall once but I was too intimidated to absorb anything, so I have absolutely no idea.

I have a really strong imagination and I world-build all the time in my head, this is a good thing right? What other personal qualities should I work on?

Anything you think would help is much appreciated - also I'm autistic so this is really intimidating for me, all the socialising aspect of it.

Comment: Welcome! I recommend browsing around our [about](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) page to get a feel for how the site works. We're a Q&A as opposed to a discussion forum. However, you do pose some valid questions. It looks to me like you might find [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8458/4089), [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/419/4089) and [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6146/4089) question useful. I'm sure some of our more avid 4e players could offer even more questions than that to help you get started.

Comment: No apology necessary :) It took me some time to get used to the SE sites as well. Your post would be great on a message board, but here the format is much more cut-and-dry. If you still have definitive curiosities (ones that could possibly have a single "best" answer) then please rephrase them into their own questions. You can even edit this post to shoot for that, once you've gotten to that stage of the process. When you've got twenty reputation, you can even drop by the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) where people can help in a much more brainstorming fashion.

Comment: Definitely, in fact browse the [tag:new-players] tag and then ask more questions about the problems you're having!

Answer (score 3):

Two things that you should keep in mind: the game is supposed to be fun and you are supposed to play a character within the world.

The first point is obvious: You should have fun otherwise this is not worth it. What is fun?  Killing monsters and looting their corpses?  Exploring thousand years old ruins?  Working out who's going to be king and helping them to amass power?  Helping Robin Hood by spying on your uncle Prince John?  This is really up to you: what are you seeking from the game?

The second point is about the game's background and how you interact with it. Learn about the world you will be playing in: what do *you* want to explore within it?  The rise of your character from plebs to mighty lord?  The journey of discovery from humble beginning being thrust into adventurous times?  Revenge on the ones who killed your father?  The latter would be more interesting if it turned out that daddy was one of the bad guys...  Anyhow, what do *you* want your character to do?  Where do you them to go?  Talk to your GM about this and ask them to incorporate as much of what you want into their adventures.

Fundamentally, the more you put into the game, the more you *should* get out of it.

A long time ago, a friend of mine wanted to try RPG.  So, we set up a game set in the Conan universe.  He wanted to play a barbarian adventure.  From the time he got his character sheet to the time we broke out to sleep (about 12 hours later) he acted and spoke in character.  Even when ordering pizza!  He jumped in with one goal: to have fun. And we all did.

Comment: @LitheOhm: I'd avoid the word wench though...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting familiar with the game you plan on playing.  Most games have a starter or lite version that you can download for free ([DnD 4e Started Edition](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/QuickStartRules.pdf)).  If you have a friend that plays, see if they will run through the system a little with you.  Being familiar with the game will help remove some of the stress and confusion that might contribute to your feeling intimidated.  I would also get an idea what your play style is.  From your question, I would guess narrative and story are important to you, more so than gaining levels or having the most powerful item.  Look for a group that has a similar play style if you can.

Comment: +1 crash courses help a lot where actual, real experience comes in. First step in teaching an inexperienced player is to give them experience, and mini-games are the best way to do that.